# Generate Random Number from specific integers

Tags: c++

I want to generate random number from specific integers 
example : generate random number from these values {2,7,9,8,11,13,16}
the generated number is one of these values

Comment: Just generate random index. Look at `<random>` facilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try somethig like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  srand ( time(NULL) ); //initialize the random seed

  const int SIZE = 7;
  const int arrayNum[SIZE] = {2,7,9,8,11,13,16};
  int RandIndex = rand() % SIZE; //generates a random number between 0 and 6
  std::cout << arrayNum[RandIndex];
}
```

Hope it helps =)

Comment: Thank you but its generate the same value every time If i want to used it in a loop ;)

Comment: are you sure that as index you used new `rand() % SIZE` each time?

`for(int i=0; i<10; i++)cout<<arrayNum[rand() % SIZE]`

Comment: @RudolfManusadzhyan `rand()` can generate identical numbers on each start. Common fix is call `rand()` several times after `srand`: `rand(); rand(); rand();`. You can even google it - it is used very often. That's why programmers MUST NOT use `rand()`, because it is a kind of shit.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is: put these values into a vector, generate a number between 0 and vector.size() using rand() and use this value as index.

Comment: Never use `rand()`, forget about it forever.

Comment: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Comment: "between 0 and vector.size()" And what happens if you will get `vector.size()` and use it as index?..

Comment: Ok. But your answer in words contains TWO horrible errors. So, your answer is incorrect. Twice.

Comment: Correct answer is in first comment to the question by Jarod42

Comment: Using rand() is not an error, despite what you say. And I think it is quite clear what is meant with _between_. Have a nice day.

Comment: Ctx, if "between" means "not including", then you again not right, you miss index 0. In any meaning your answer is not good.

Comment: And never use `rand()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer i will try it  @vladon